# Trying to set a GeoCoordinate with lat/lon when object is created. C# WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I'm creating multiple Bus objects with json data from an API. After they are created I want to create a GeoCoordinate to hold the longitude and latitude. I'm new to C# and can't seem to figure out why this doesn't work? Thanks in advance for any input.

```
 class Bus
{
        public string id { get; set; }
        public double longitude { get; set; }
        public double latitude { get; set; }
        public string route { get; set; }
        public string lastStop { get; set; }
        public GeoCoordinate busLocation { get; set; }



        public Bus()
        {
           GeoCoordinate busLocation = new GeoCoordinate(latitude, longitude);
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what your code trying to do. Checking `busLocation` for null there is useless, it is always null at the moment constructor get called. I think you want to instantiate `busLocation` property instead :

```
public Bus()
{
    busLocation = new GeoCoordinate();
}
```

so that later you can assign value to it's `Latitude` and `Longitude` property, for example :

```
myBus.busLocation.Latitude = 50d;
myBus.busLocation.Longitude = 50d;
```

Comment: I changed it to try to use this code:

    `public Bus()
            
{
                GeoCoordinate busLocation = new GeoCoordinate(latitude, longitude);
             }`

But when I call myBus.busLocation it is null.

Comment: that code you tried creates new local variable named `busLocation` instead of assigning value to predefined global variable/property. Remove `GeoCoordinate` from your code : `busLocation = new GeoCoordinate(latitude, longitude);`